# PDO get fractional seconds from Postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, php-7

When I query datetime fields from `postgresql (9.6)` with a simple pdo statement `(PHP7)`

```
$sql = "SELECT date FROM table"
$stmt = $adapter->createStatement($sql);
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
```

I receive the string `2017-02-03 15:51:44` instead of `2017-02-03 15:51:44.240000` (the last outpout is result from psql console)

I saw a post talking about
[this bug report FROM 2011 about mysql and php 5](http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-bugs/11524dvh68/php-bug-bug-54648-new-pdo-forces-format-of-datetime-fields), I guess since 2011 the problem have been fixed or people have find a way to fix this.

Anyone found a solution to retrieve the fractional seconds in php ?

Comment: What is data type for your `date` column ?

Comment: TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE

Comment: Try please my answer below and check what result it gives for you

Comment: You can use to_char with the format you want :)

Comment: Thank you @ClémentPrévost I will use **SELECT to_char(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS') FROM table** but since I don't build the sql request and I don't really know which field are date, I think it's not the best way to have a regex that modify the Sql request to wrap every datetime fields :(

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you make it a varchar?

```
$sql = "SELECT date::varchar FROM table"
```

Comment: this query return **2017-02-03 15:51:44** in both psql and pdo and I need the fractional seconds

Comment: Just for the record, if you run "select current_timestamp" in psql do you get any fractional seconds?

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone found a solution to retrieve the fractional seconds in php ?

They're normally part of the result.
Here's actual code that retrieves a timestamp with a default php-7.1.2 install:

```
<?php
$link = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=test;host=localhost", $user, $password);

$stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT '2016-01-02 22:44:31.625129'::timestamp AS t");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch();
print_r($result);
?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [t] => 2016-01-02 22:44:31.625129
    [0] => 2016-01-02 22:44:31.625129
)
```

So there's nothing special to do to keep these microseconds, it would be to discard them that some additional code would be needed, or a truncate in SQL or a cast to `timestamp(0)`.