# how to change rails migration t.timestamps to use `timestamp(0) without timezone` in postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, timestamp

I'm trying to figure out how to change the native data type that `t.timestamps` uses in a rails migration. Default type that ends up in postgres is `timestamp without timezone`. What I would like instead is `timestamp(0) without timezone`.

I'd like to change the native data type so that when a new table is created and `t.timestamps` is used in the migration, it automatically creates the correct timestamp data type.

I require `timestamp(0) without timezone` because my rails application shares its DB with a laravel application and both applications can insert data. Due to the fact that rails uses milliseconds/laravel does not, and there doesn't seem to be a way ( as of 2018-10-23 ) for laravel to support having a table that contains different formats of timestamps (`Y-m-d H:i:s.u` vs `Y-m-d H:i:s`) without having to turn off timestamps in the model, essentially disabling the auto management of them, I'd like to have the database enforce the use of a single format(`Y-m-d H:i:s`).

For more details please my other question:  [Is there a way to change Rails default timestamps to Y-m-d H:i:s (instead of Y-m-d H:i:s.u) or have laravel ignore decimal portion of Y-m-d H:i:s.u?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864581/is-there-a-way-to-change-rails-default-timestamps-to-y-m-d-his-instead-of-y-m)

So I want to use `timestamp(0)` to truncate the milliseconds and not have to think about setting the tables timestamp types correctly when creating a new table, as the native type would already be `timestamp(0)`

I've tried this

```
./config/environments/initializers

require "active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter"

module ActiveRecord
 module ConnectionAdapters
   class PostgreSQLAdapter
     NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES.merge!(
      timestamp: { name: "timestamp(0) without timezone" }
     )
   end
 end
end
```

and a migration like

```
class ChangeTimestampTypesToTimestamp0 < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :test, id: :uuid, default: -> { "gen_random_uuid()" } do|t|
      t.string :name, null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

but that did not work.

I also tried to change the timestamp to use timestampz with the same migration above as a sanity check, still no luck...

```
require "active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter"

module ActiveRecord
 module ConnectionAdapters
   class PostgreSQLAdapter
     NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES.merge!(
       timestamp: { name: "timestamptz" }
     )
   end
 end
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe I've figure it out!

I started looking into what NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES were bring set by print out the variable from the console

```
Rails c
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES
```

Result:
`{:primary_key=>"bigserial primary key", :string=>{:name=>"character varying"}, :text=>{:name=>"text"}, :integer=>{:name=>"integer", :limit=>4}, :float=>{:name=>"float"}, :decimal=>{:name=>"decimal"}, :datetime=>{:name=>"timestamp"}, :time=>{:name=>"time"}, :date=>{:name=>"date"}, :daterange=>{:name=>"daterange"}, :numrange=>{:name=>"numrange"}, :tsrange=>{:name=>"tsrange"}, :tstzrange=>{:name=>"tstzrange"}, :int4range=>{:name=>"int4range"}, :int8range=>{:name=>"int8range"}, :binary=>{:name=>"bytea"}, :boolean=>{:name=>"boolean"}, :xml=>{:name=>"xml"}, :tsvector=>{:name=>"tsvector"}, :hstore=>{:name=>"hstore"}, :inet=>{:name=>"inet"}, :cidr=>{:name=>"cidr"}, :macaddr=>{:name=>"macaddr"}, :uuid=>{:name=>"uuid"}, :json=>{:name=>"json"}, :jsonb=>{:name=>"jsonb"}, :ltree=>{:name=>"ltree"}, :citext=>{:name=>"citext"}, :point=>{:name=>"point"}, :line=>{:name=>"line"}, :lseg=>{:name=>"lseg"}, :box=>{:name=>"box"}, :path=>{:name=>"path"}, :polygon=>{:name=>"polygon"}, :circle=>{:name=>"circle"}, :bit=>{:name=>"bit"}, :bit_varying=>{:name=>"bit varying"}, :money=>{:name=>"money"}, :interval=>{:name=>"interval"}, :oid=>{:name=>"oid"}`

turns out that `timestamp` was never actually set before I started including it with my

```
module ActiveRecord
 module ConnectionAdapters
   class PostgreSQLAdapter
     NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES.merge!(
      timestamp: { name: "timestamp", limit:0 }
     )
   end
 end
end
```

What was being included thought was `datetime` and I realized that `timestamp` was an alias of `datetime`.

I changed the NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES merge to look like this...

```
require "active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter"

module ActiveRecord
 module ConnectionAdapters
   class PostgreSQLAdapter
     NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES.merge!(
       datetime: { name: "timestamp", limit:0 }
     )
   end
 end
end
```

I ran my migration and the columns were successfully set to `timestamp(0) without timezone`

Comment: Note: I have just noticed this answer. It seems the difference between this answer and mine is my answer preserves the default `timestamp` property in Rails and alters those for `created_at` and `updated_at` only. This answer makes a global change for `datetiime` in general.  Which is more suitable is up to user's need, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution.  It alters the default timestamp precision in Rails, including for migration, for the two timestamps to one second accuracy in PostgreSQL.  It's neither easy nor simple, but works for Rails 5.2 with PostgreSQL.

I think the initializer should be placed in `config/initializers/` (not in `environments`).
Write the following file.

```
# ./config/initializers/arbitrary.rb

require "active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb"
require "active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter"
require "active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements"
require "active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements"
require "active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter"

module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    # Overwrites a method in /abstract/schema_definitions.rb
    class TableDefinition
      def timestamps(**options)
        options[:null] = false if options[:null].nil?

        column(:created_at, :datetime0, options)
        column(:updated_at, :datetime0, options)
      end
    end

    # Overwrites a method in /abstract/schema_statements.rb
    module SchemaStatements
      def add_timestamps(table_name, options = {})
        options[:null] = false if options[:null].nil?
    
        add_column table_name, :created_at, :datetime0, options
        add_column table_name, :updated_at, :datetime0, options
      end
    end

    # Overwrites a method in /postgresql/schema_statements.rb
    module PostgreSQL
      module SchemaStatements
        def add_timestamps_for_alter(table_name, options = {})
          [add_column_for_alter(table_name, :created_at, :datetime0, options), add_column_for_alter(table_name, :updated_at, :datetime0, options)]
        end
      end
    end

    # Modifies a constant and methods in /postgresql_adapter.rb
    class PostgreSQLAdapter
      alias_method :initialize_type_map_orig, :initialize_type_map if ! self.method_defined?(:initialize_type_map_orig)
      NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:datetime0] = { name: "timestamp(0)" }

      private    
        def initialize_type_map(m = type_map)
          register_class_with_precision_t0 m, "timestamp0", OID::DateTime
          initialize_type_map_orig(m)
        end

        def register_class_with_precision_t0(mapping, key, klass)
          mapping.register_type(key) do |*args|
            klass.new(precision: 0)
          end
        end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is an example migration file.

```
# db/migrate/20181023182238_create_articles.rb
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Migration (`bin/rails db:migrate`) creates a table `articles` with the two timestamps columns of `timestamp(0)` (without timezone) in the PostgreSQL database.

The SQL executed is this:

```
CREATE TABLE "articles" (
  "id" bigserial primary key, 
  "title" character varying, 
  "created_at" timestamp(0) NOT NULL,
  "updated_at" timestamp(0) NOT NULL);
```

### Note

I have confirmed both migration to create a table and data updating works in Rails console.  It is meant to work in a migration to update a table, too, but I haven't tested it.

With a bit more tweaking it would work in other databases as well.

Basically the code above defines a new Rails type `timestamp0`, to which `timestamps()` (which is `created_at` and `updated_at`) is assigned.
If you want any other columns of timestamp to be the same (i.e., no sub-second precision in the DB), specify `timestamp0` in your migration and it should work (although I haven't tested it).