# Comparing times in postgres and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, parsing, time, comparison

Very simply put, I have a query:

```
@current_user.items.where('updated_at > ? AND updated_at < ?', last_sync_time_from_client, current_time)
```

My problem is, I think the time being compared in the database and the `last_sync_time_from_client` are being compared on a float basis. This always results in the `updated_at > last_sync_time_from_client` being true even when the time is identical to the second.

I.e.

```
(db item)updated_at.to_f # 1541246811.022979
last_sync_time.to_f # 1541246811.0
```

This means that the times, which are the same down to the second, will return oddities. Is there a way to fix this, or should I simply add a second to the last_sync_time_from_client to account for Rails being strange here?

Comment: Nothing is strange here. Seconds are not the smallest unit of time. You can [truncate the date to the second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10213289/2697183) if your logic dictates that, but I don't see why you should. Don't you want to return the items that were updated 1 millisecond after the `last_sync_time_from_client`? Do you also expect the `updated_at` to be in the future? If not, then ensuring that it is less than current_time is not necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three solutions.  Solution 1 is the best (non-destructive).  Solutions 2 and 3 affect the stored values in database directly, and so choose it at your own risk.

### Solution 1

Use

```
date_trunc('second', updated_at);
```

instead of `updated_at`.
See [the answer to "Discard millisecond part from timestamp"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213190/discard-millisecond-part-from-timestamp/10213289#10213289) for detail.

### Solution 2

Force Rails always to update the timestamp with the precision of a second, truncating the sub-second part to zero.

See [an answer to "Is there a way to change Rails default timestamps to Y-m-d H:i:s (instead of Y-m-d H:i:s.u) or have laravel ignore decimal portion of Y-m-d H:i:s.u?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52864581/is-there-a-way-to-change-rails-default-timestamps-to-y-m-d-his-instead-of-y-m/52866224#52866224)

### Solution 3

Make the precision of the `updated_at` column in the database a second, as opposed to the default sub-second (like a milli-second).

See [the answers to "how to change rails migration t.timestamps to use `timestamp(0) without timezone` in postgres"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953885/how-to-change-rails-migration-t-timestamps-to-use-timestamp0-without-timezone) for how to do it with Rails migration.

Comment: Thank you. I realized that there was a problem with my own code - I should have been keeping the milliseconds in the first place, but I accepted this answer because it's really informative.